# Updating WooCommerce menu_order after post is saved

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to set a product's menu_order value when a new post/product is published like so:

```
function set_post_to_last_order($post_id, $post_after, $post_before) {
 if (get_post_type($post_id) === 'product'):
    if (($post_before->post_status === 'auto-draft' || $post_before->post_status === 'draft') && $post_after->post_status === 'publish'):
        $product = new WC_Product($post_id);

        $products = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);

        $product->set_menu_order($products->post_count + 1);
    endif;
  endif;
}
```

And that function runs on the `post_updated` action.

```
add_action('post_updated', 'set_post_to_last_order', 100, 3);
```

It essentially sets the menu order to be 1 more than the total amount of products. The function runs correctly and sets the menu order, however, it's overridden by the form values in the custom fields within the post, which by default on new Products is set to 0. I expected `post_updated` to fire *after* the fields are saved not before. Is there a way to get the function to run after the $_POST request runs on publish/save?

Comment: `set_menu_order` calls `$this->set_prop`, I am not sure if that actually writes through to the database - or just updates the properties of the PHP object instance. I think you might need to explicitly call the `save` method afterwards …?

Comment: @CBroe how would I go about saving it?

Comment: By calling the `save` method …?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah that was the stupidest question I've asked in a long while.

Comment: @CBroe Legend, that's worked a treat. After all that.

Answer (score 0):

Question has been answered by @CBroe.

```
$product->save()
```

Was required.